# Disable past days in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar with agendaWeek as defaultView. How can i make past days as non selectable .

For ex today is 15th August and i don't want to let user to select dates older , like on 13th August.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best solution is to use the option validRange

```
 validRange: {
        start: today,
        end: '2025-06-01'
    },
```

where

```
var  today = new Date();
```

end the end date is some date in distant future.